# Inheritance of a class depending on another inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance

### Existing structure

I'm modeling an Epub book.
An Epub is basically a `.zip` file containing `.html` documents as the chapters.
so that is the structure I followed for my classes.

`Epub` is a class,
that deals with opening the zip file,
finding and extracting the chapter names,
and creates a list of `Chapter`s.
The `Chapter` class deals with reading the file,
parsing it with BeautifulSoup
and extracting the paragraphs.

This structure works very well,
and does everything I need.

Here I show an extremely stripped down version of the two classes,
just to have an idea of the structure (it is not usable):

```py
class Epub:
    def __init__(self, zipped_file):
        # load the book in memory and fill in several attributes
        # [more things to do...]
        self.chap_file_names = [str(p) for p in self.chap_file_paths]
        # build a list of chapters
        self.chapters: list[Chapter] = [
            Chapter(self.input_zip.read(chap_file_name))
            for chap_file_name in self.chap_file_names
        ]

class Chapter:
    def __init__(self, chap_content):
        # parse the soup and get the body
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(chap_content, features="html.parser")
        self.body = self.soup.body
        # find the paragraphs
        self.all_p_tag = self.body.find_all("p")
```

### Extending the classes

The problem is that now I need to extend *both* classes to add additional functionalities.
Lets call them `EpubTrad` and `ChapterTrad`.

If I just do something like `class EpubTrad(Epub):`,
this works well for all the various `chap_file_names` and similar attributes;
`ChapterTrad` should also inherit from `Chapter`,
as the `soup` and other attributes are perfectly fine and needed.

However, I run into the following problem:
when I instantiate an `EpubTrad` object
the attribute `chapters` will be a list of `Chapters`,
while I want that to be a list of `ChapterTrad`.

How could I fix that?

### Possible solution: split `__init__`

One of the workaround I could try is to
defer the creation of the list:

```py
class Epub:
    def __init__(
        self,
        zipped_file: Union[str, IO[bytes], Path],
    ) -> None:
        # load the book in memory and fill in several attributes
        self.chap_file_names = [str(p) for p in self.chap_file_paths]

    def parse_chapters(self):
        # build a list of chapters
        self.chapters: list[Chapter] = [
            Chapter(self.input_zip.read(chap_file_name))
            for chap_file_name in self.chap_file_names
        ]

class EpubTrad(Epub):
    def __init__(
        self,
        zipped_file: Union[str, IO[bytes], Path],
        lang: str,
    ) -> None:
        # load the book in memory and fill in epub attributes
        super().__init__(zipped_file)
        # do more init related to trad things
        self.lang = lang

    def parse_chapters(self):
        # build a list of trad chapters
        self.chapters: list[ChapterTrad] = [
            ChapterTrad(self.input_zip.read(chap_file_name))
            for chap_file_name in self.chap_file_names
        ]

    def cool_trad_func(self):
        """Do fancy trad-related things."""
```

and use the classes like this:

```py
>>> ep = Epub("book.epub")
>>> ep.parse_chapters()
>>> ept = EpubTrad("book.epub")
>>> ept.parse_chapters()
```

Of course if I had more things to do in `__init__` after parsing the chapters
that would need to be in yet another func like `finish_init`.

There is also a bit of fiddling left to do as `Chapter` and `ChapterTrad`
would need to be split in a similar way,
because `Chapter`s actually contain a list of `Paragraph`s,
that also need to be extended as `ParagraphTrad`,
but the question is chaotic enough as it is now.

### In short

`Epub` is a class that in the constructor creates a list of `Chapter`s.
How can I inherit from `Epub` to `EpubTrad` and make it so that
the list is made of `ChapterTrad`, that inherit from `Chapter`?

Cheers!

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `Chapter` in `EPub.__init__`, make `EPub` generic in the class used to represent chapters. That class can be provided as a class attribute or as an argument to `EPub.__init__`.

Comment: @chepner sorry, I might have stripped too many details from `EpubTrad`: the class does not differ from `Epub` only in the type of the list of chapters, but also adds more attributes in the constructor and more functions. I have edited the question to highlight this.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle. Instead of `Epub` defining how chapters are represented, the user tells `Epub` how to define a chapter.